# UNIX timestamp (= seconds since 1/1/1970) in document?

Tags: datetime, isodate

I would like to include a so-called UNIX timestamp in my document. All technicalities aside, it's basically the number of seconds since 1/1/1970 0:00 UTC aka "the epoch". (At the time of me writing this, it's 1385812869.)

If have not found a way to include that number in my document. Unless I have overlooked something, the obvious suspects (datetime, isodate, scrtime) seem not to provide a ready-made solution.

Comment: What is the purpose of this number? What we can do with it?

Comment: @Sigur: It's the UNIX way of keeping time, allowing you to easily and unambiguously specify a point in time, down to the second, without having to worry about DST, time zones, etc. etc. But surely this is beyond the scope of this forum?

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading about it but I can not imagine how to use it. But now, I have some ideas.

Comment: @Ingmar: you wish! It has leap seconds.

Comment: I said "all technicalities aside", didn't I? Also, we're talking about 25 or so leap seconds since 1972. I can live with that.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

```
pdflatex \\def\\epoch{`date +%s`}\\input ep.tex
```

the exact form of quoting on the command line depends on your shell (this is bash)

where `ep.tex` is

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

now = \epoch.


\end{document}
```

---

If you want to calculate it portably in classic TeX (actually I used etex, arithmetic but that could be easily removed) you can do this (which actually is exactly 1 day out in my system, so you could either fix my arithmetic or just add a day at the start:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

now1 = \epoch.
\newcount\tepoch

\count0=\numexpr\year-1970\relax
\tepoch=\numexpr\count0*365*24*60*60\relax

\count2=\count0
\divide\count2 4

%extra day for each leap year (avoid complication of mod 100 and mod 400, so we are good until 2100
\advance\tepoch\numexpr\count2*24*60*60\relax

% extra whatever for each whole month
\ifnum\month>1 \advance\tepoch\numexpr 31*24*60*60\relax \fi

\ifnum\numexpr4*\count2\relax=\count0
  \ifnum\month>2 \advance\tepoch\numexpr 29*24*60*60\relax \fi
\else
  \ifnum\month>2 \advance\tepoch\numexpr 28*24*60*60\relax \fi
\fi

\ifnum\month>3 \advance\tepoch\numexpr 31*24*60*60\relax \fi
\ifnum\month>4 \advance\tepoch\numexpr 30*24*60*60\relax \fi
\ifnum\month>5 \advance\tepoch\numexpr 31*24*60*60\relax \fi
\ifnum\month>6 \advance\tepoch\numexpr 30*24*60*60\relax \fi
\ifnum\month>7 \advance\tepoch\numexpr 31*24*60*60\relax \fi
\ifnum\month>8 \advance\tepoch\numexpr 31*24*60*60\relax \fi
\ifnum\month>9 \advance\tepoch\numexpr 30*24*60*60\relax \fi
\ifnum\month>10 \advance\tepoch\numexpr 31*24*60*60\relax \fi
\ifnum\month>11 \advance\tepoch\numexpr 30*24*60*60\relax \fi

% seconds from previous days in this month
\advance\tepoch\numexpr (\day-1)*24*60*60\relax

% seconds from today
\advance\tepoch\numexpr \time*60\relax


now2 = \the\tepoch.

diff = \the\numexpr(\epoch-\tepoch)/(60*60)\relax\ hours

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, a system command seems like an obvious answer. Probably won't work across environments, though, will it? Will have to test this with Windows.

Comment: @Ingmar well I ran that on windows (using cygwin)  but yes using a system call does of course introduce system dependencies.

Comment: *Its an ingenious solution to a problem that should never have existed in the first place. [James May]*

Comment: A platform independent solution might exist via `lualatex`. I'm no expert of luatex but I'm sure there should be some `lua` functions for date/time conversions.

Comment: @Pouya You could calculate it in TeX (from \year \month \day and \time and a macro holding information about any leap seconds, it's just easier not to bother:-)

Comment: Looks as though there won't be an easy, portable solution that can be expected to work across systems... I'll probably settle for the much more mundane timestamp, as in "1970-01-01 0:00:00 GMT" ... Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: @Ingmar calculating it from within TeX can't be that hard, if it's a requirement, ping here if you want me to update the answer.

Comment: @Pouya Operating systems have their own concept of Epoch; it's true that Unix Epoch is “standardized”, but there's no guarantee that the underlying operating system provides a system call for it. What is (almost) surely guaranteed is that the OS provides system calls for the current day and time and TeX uses those.

Comment: @Ingmar `pdflatex` and `lualatex` provide `\pdfcreationdate`.

Comment: @Ingmar portable tex version added

Comment: You don't take into account the leap seconds; but since TeX doesn't provide seconds, it's not really relevant.

Comment: @egreg wikipedia said not to worry about leap seconds for unix time (if I understood it correctly) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time But I must have something else wrong as I'm a day out:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why `(\day-1)`?

Comment: @egreg on the 1st of the month there are 0 complete days to add so you just want to calculate the seconds from this day.

Comment: Time zone information isn't available in TeX, is it? Without it, there is no possible solution to the problem. Though I suppose one could provide it in a separate file to be `\input`, as most computers don't change time zone too often. Or you could just set the appropriate environment variable: `TZ=UTC pdflatex …`.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen ah good point (although I'm living in GMT at the moment:-) you could have an offset variable you'd only have to change when the clocks changed, you could set the env variable outside, but if you do that you may as well stick with the inital idea of running date externally

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, There have been 11 leap years since 1970, not (2013-1970)/4 = 10. There is a leap year in the middle of each quartet of years from 1970 to 2010, plus another one in the last 3 years. Use (\year-1969)/4.

Answer (score 7):

This works with `pdflatex` and `lualatex`, with `--shell-escape`; of course it's system dependent and will work only on Unix systems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\makeatletter
\CatchFileEdef{\epoch}{|"date -j +\@percentchar s"}{\endlinechar=\m@ne}
\CatchFileEdef{\timestamp}{|"date -j"}{\endlinechar=\m@ne}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\epoch

\timestamp

\pdfcreationdate % this is available also without shell escape
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Apart from interesting [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147699/22492) by David and his [suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147698/unix-timestamp-seconds-since-1-1-1970-in-document#comment335215_147699) about calculating it manually, here is my solution based on `luatex`. Please note that this is just a guideline and the code is neither clean nor complete by any means. There are lots of rooms for improvements!

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
    function epoch (format,time)
    if format == 1 then
      fmt = "%c"
    elseif format == 2 then
      fmt = "%A"
    elseif format == 3 then
      fmt = "%B"
    elseif format == 4 then
      fmt = "%X"
    else
      fmt = "%x"
    end
    tex.sprint(os.date(fmt, time))
    end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\epoch[2]{\directlua{epoch(#1,#2)}}

\begin{document}
This is a test. We now check the time stamp for 1385817087
\begin{itemize}
    \item \%c \epoch{1}{1385817087}
    \item \%A \epoch{2}{1385817087}
    \item \%B \epoch{3}{1385817087}
    \item \%X \epoch{4}{1385817087}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

You have to compile this by `lualatex myfile.tex`. Other options for using `lua` function `os.date` can be found [here](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html).

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 2):

To supplement that part of David Carlisle's answer which uses the POSIX `date` utility, here is a way to get the epoch on Windows.

On Windows the "epoch time" concept not only implemented in Unix-like environments and their utilities, but also in the standard C library functions implemented in the Microsoft Visual C Library.

That is to say, Microsoft's  `<time.h>` material is based on a Unix-like `time_t` whose units are seconds, and which measures since the Epoch. This is not required by ISO C, but it helps port code which assumes that representation.

So you can make yourself some trimmed down `epoch.exe` with Visual C that prints the time.

I just compiled this code with VS2008 into a Win32 console application.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("%ld\n", (long) time(0));
   return 0;
}
```

The statically-linked (no dependency on a `msvcrt.dll`) executable (156 kB) is [here](http://kylheku.com/~kaz/epoch.exe).

Comment: Did you not notice which stackexchange this is? Your answer isn't exactly TeX-relevant.

Comment: @Random832 Some other answers give a solution based on running the POSIX `date` utility and interpolating the result into the TeX. OP was concerned that it won't work on Windows, which doesn't have the `date` utility, unless some form of Unix emulation layer is installed. This is a possible way to address that issue without installing a whole environment. I clarified this in the answer now.