# pgfplots: How to put arbitrary text at the X axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a fairly basic plot like this (only three values for brevity here):

```
 \documentclass{standalone}

 \usepackage{pgfplots}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis} [
 axis y line*=left,
 xlabel=$t$,
 ylabel=$SomeUnit$,
 no marks,
 legend cell align={left},
 legend style={at={(0,-0.1)},anchor=north west}
 ]

 \addplot coordinates {
    (0.000000,2.2604616420110846)
    (0.059999,2.4530650447747706)
    (0.119999,2.4052869003392985)
 };
 \addlegendentry{Foo}

 \addplot coordinates {
    (0.000000,7.09148443572902)
    (0.059999,7.167237825210513)
    (0.119999,7.048386141043992)
 };
 \addlegendentry{Bar}

 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

This TeX code is generated by another program.

When I render it, it looks as expected:
[image: Rendered picture]

What I need now is text ticks at the X axes. The X axis represents points in time (in seconds) and "0" is a specific date, let's say 2018-09-10 13:37:58. So, I want:

1. The whole date as the first tick
2. Only the time at the other ticks
3. Whenever a new day starts (sometimes the measurements go over night), a tick with the new date

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One starting (possibly easy) way is to use `lua-scripts` and compile your document using `lualatex`. Having said that you can get something like:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{luacode}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147698/unix-timestamp-seconds-since-1-1-1970-in-document
\begin{luacode*}
    function epoch (time)
    fmt = "%m-%d-%Y %X"
    tex.sprint(os.date(fmt, time))
    end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\epoch[1]{\directlua{epoch(#1)}}
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
axis y line*=left,
xlabel=$t$,
ylabel=$SomeUnit$,
no marks,
legend cell align={left},
legend style={at={(0,-0.1)},anchor=north west},
xtick = data,
xticklabels={\epoch{1536579478}},
xticklabel style={rotate=45, anchor=east}
]

\addplot coordinates {
    (0.000000,2.2604616420110846)
    (0.059999,2.4530650447747706)
    (0.119999,2.4052869003392985)
};
\addlegendentry{Foo}

\addplot coordinates {
    (0.000000,7.09148443572902)
    (0.059999,7.167237825210513)
    (0.119999,7.048386141043992)
};
\addlegendentry{Bar}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This will give you:

[image]

Either you can fill in the `UNIX` time by yourself, or adjust the `lua` code to fit your need.

Comment: Funny, I just wanted to answer my own question with an answer similar to this.

Comment: @rabejens But you must take into account that this is just a starting point, and not really **THE** solution ;) but I think all variants of the answers are welcome!

Comment: Yes, I know, for example, you give a fixed timestamp. One must use `\tick` here and convert this to a number because it is a string. I also have to implement my own tick label system, since depending on the amount of data I want to have different ticks. I think I'll supply some look-up table as I generate this TeX code anyway.